# Floating tab on page?

Tags: php, javascript

I'm looking to create a simple page tab... thing.

The issue is, I don't even know the proper terminology for them. I'm talking about those little tabs that stick to one side of the window, they're commonly used for support windows.

Here's an example: http://www.livechatinc.com/ (bottom right)

Could someone give me the code for one? and I'll modify it appropriately. I just want a simple image that links to another page.

Thanks.

Comment: You'd be able to do this using javascript and a simply CSS `position: fixed; bottom: 0px; right: 0px;`

Comment: http://www.jtricks.com/javascript/navigation/floating.html Something like this?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it's an html problem, you can fixe a block bottom left like that :

html :

```
<div id="stick"><img src="myimg" /></div>
```

css :

```
#stick{
width:100px;
height:50px;
position:fixed;
top:100%;
left:100px;
margin-top:-50px;
margin-left:-100px
}
```

That's is you want to do ?

Comment: Yeah, that's it. How do I add a link to that? So that clicking on the image takes the user to a page.

Comment: you have to create a div with same coordinate where you want to it display with y axis

Comment: <div id="stick"><a href="#yourlink"><img src="myimg" /></a></div>
You have just to do that no ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use jquery + css combination with technique to do it

you can also go with plugin 
here is one plugin 
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/create-a-tabbed-interface-using-jquery/